# NetLogo - Errors during the setup with GIS extension

Tags: gis, netlogo, shapefile, qgis

I'm trying to load some shapefiles in Netlogo with the extension gis but it don't work. When I click on the button "initialisation" I have this error :

> Extension exception: unsupported shape type 15
> error while observer running GIS:LOAD-DATASET
> called by procedure INITIALISATION
> called by Button 'Initialisation'

This button change the color of patches to white for the world. So even if I have this error, it can load a white background...

Then, I'm trying to load some shapefiles : font (municipality of Genevois a natural region of Haute-Savoie/Upper Savoy,France), hydrology (lakes and rivers), urban areas and mountain (above 1250 meters).

The button for loading the font and urban areas works, that's not the case of the others shapefiles, I have this error :

> Extension exception: not a VectorFeature, Agent, AgentSet, or List: 0.0
> error while observer running GIS:INTERSECTING
> called by procedure IMPORT.MOUNTAIN
> called by Button 'Montagne'
> That's the same error for hydrology.

Do you know how can I solve these errors ?

Here is my code :

````
;; Ajout de l'extension gis pour integrer des zones géographiques
extensions [ gis ]
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Creation des variables globales
globals 
[
  font-dataset
  urban-dataset
  hydrology-dataset
  mountain-dataset
]

patches-own
[
  font?             ;; indicates if the cell is sea
  urban?           ;; indicates if the cell is urban
  hydrology?
  mountain?
]
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; initialisation
to total.initialisation
  ca
end

to initialisation
   ask patches[
    set pcolor white
    set font? false
    set urban? false
    set hydrology? false
    set mountain? false
  ]
  set font-dataset gis:load-dataset "font.shp"
  set urban-dataset gis:load-dataset "urban.shp"
  set hydrology-dataset gis:load-dataset "hydrology.shp"
  set mountain-dataset gis:load-dataset "mountain.shp"
  reset-ticks
end
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;import data
to import.all
  import.font
  import.urban
  import.hydrology
  import.mountain
end

to import.font
  ask patches gis:intersecting font-dataset
  [
     set font? true
      set urban? false
      set hydrology? false
      set mountain? false
      set pcolor 58
  ]
end


to import.urban
  ask patches gis:intersecting urban-dataset
  [
   set urban? true
    set font? false
    set hydrology? false
    set mountain? false
    set pcolor 16
  ]
end

to import.hydrology
   ask patches gis:intersecting hydrology-dataset
  [
    set hydrology? true
    set font? false
    set urban? false
    set mountain? false
    set pcolor 96
  ]
end

to import.mountain
   ask patches gis:intersecting mountain-dataset
  [
    set mountain? true
    set font? false
    set urban? false
    set hydrology? false
    set pcolor 34
  ]
end ```
````

Comment: this looks like the GIS dataset has something not standard in it (or maybe newer standard than the NetLogo GIS extension recognises). Can you try it with other GIS files?

Comment: Hello JenB, I tried to create a new shapefile for the mountains but I have the same error

```Extension exception: unsupported shape type 15
error while observer running GIS:LOAD-DATASET
  called by procedure INITIALISATION
  called by Button 'Initialisation'

Extension exception: not a VectorFeature, Agent, AgentSet, or List: 0.0
error while observer running GIS:INTERSECTING
  called by procedure IMPORT.MOUNTAIN
  called by Button 'Montagne'```

Comment: It works ! I simply reversed import.urban with import.hydrology and import.mountain and it worked! I don't really understand why... !